# Perek of Tehilim for someone else's spiritual growth

Tags: tefilla, torah-study, tehilim-psalms

Is there a perek of tehilim that is particularly apropos to daven for someone else's spiritual growth (particularly in Torah learning)?

Comment: seeker, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for bringing your question here! I hope you get some great suggestions here, and that you also look around the site and find other content of interest, perhaps starting with our 100+ other [tag:tehilim] questions. May we all merit to grow, and to help each other to grow.

Answer (score 1):

[DailyTehillim.com](http://www.dailytehillim.com/Default.aspx?CategoryOption=True) suggests the tehillim to say for before learning Torah is:

[image]

Presumably, these pesukim would not only help those who wish to learn Torah themselves but also those who you daven for to be able to learn Torah as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is [Psalms 41](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2641.htm) which could be applied to the situation:

> Happy is he that considereth the underprivileged; the LORD will deliver him in the day of evil.
>
> The LORD preserve him, and keep him alive, let him be called happy in the land; and deliver not Thou him unto the greed of his enemies.
>
> The LORD support him upon the bed of illness; mayest Thou turn all his lying down in his sickness.

Comment: Got something against praying for others serial commentless downvoter?